# Solve: $xu_x + yu_y+ \frac{1}{2}(u^2_x+u^2_y) =u, u(x, 0) =\frac{1}{2}(1−x^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

In the plane find two solutions of the initial-value problem
$xu_x + yu_y+ \frac{1}{2}(u^2_x+u^2_y) =u, u(x, 0) =\frac{1}{2}(1−x^2)$.
I think we get to use the method of characteristics But I am not much familiar how to get started? Could you please guide me?

Comment: What is the meaning of your symbol $u_x^2$ ? Is it $\frac{\partial(u^2)}{\partial x}$ or $\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 ?$

Comment: yep @ JJaccquelin7. can you show me some further steps according to Frits Veerman method.

Comment: Please, first answer to my question.

Comment: Sorry, it means your second one:  \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2

Comment: In this case, the method suggested by Frits Veerman is the simplest one. From the polynomial expression of $u(x,y)$ compute $u_x$ and $u_y$. Put them into the ODE. Expand and collect all the coefficients of $x^2,y^2,xy,x,y,1$ Let each one be equal to $0$. Solve the system of equations obtained. Together with the boundary conditions, this leads to the values of $A,B,C,D,E,F$.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use an Ansatz of the form
\begin{equation}
 u(x,y) = A x^2 + 2 B x y + C y^2 + D x + E y + F,
\end{equation}
and try to determine possible values for $A$ to $F$ using the initial condition and the PDE. The method of characteristics would give you the same result, but you'll have to use the [fully nonlinear version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Fully_nonlinear_case).

Comment: @ Frits veerman. Still I  Could not able to solve it. I haven't seen such problem before.

Comment: Ok, for starters: your proposed solution should obey the initial condition, i.e. $u(x,0) = \frac{1}{2}(1-x^2)$. For our general quadratic in $x$ and $y$, substituting $y=0$ yields $u(x,0) = A x^2 + D x + F$. From this, you see that we have to choose $A = -\frac{1}{2}$, $D=0$ and $F=\frac{1}{2}$. You can follow the same procedure when substituting the proposed solution in the PDE.

Comment: @ Frits Veerman, I just guessed out that $u(x, 0) =\frac{1}{2}(1−x^2) +y $.or $u(x, 0) =\frac{1}{2}(1−x^2) -y$ are two solutions but I could not able to find these out thoroughly.

Comment: @user45993 : Put your guessed solutions $u(x,y)=(\frac{1}{2}(1-x^2)\pm y )$ into the ODE and into the boundary condition. If all agree, this is the proof that the solutions are correct. No need to prouve more.

Comment: Exactly as @JJacquelin says: the fact that these guessed functions solve the PDE is sufficient proof for the fact that they are solutions to the PDE.